# PHP code does not work as a function to find location using IP address

Tags: php

I am using the code below to find the location of an IP address. This is an API to a web service provider. The code below is working fine. However, when I try to make it work as a function, it does not work. When I check the syntax of the working code it passes. When I check the code that includes a call to the function, the syntax checker comes with the following error:

PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in your code on line 6.

Your help in solving this problem is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Menachem

This is the working code. Below this code you will find the code with the function and a call to this function. The code with the function does not work.

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use GeoIp2\WebService\Client;


// This creates a Client object that can be reused across requests.
// Replace "42" with your user ID and "license_key" with your license
// key.

$client = new Client(42, 'jijlki765');

// Replace "city" with the method corresponding to the web service that
// you are using, e.g., "country", "insights".

$ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$record = $client->city($ipAddress);

$country = $record->country->name;
$region =  $record->mostSpecificSubdivision->name;
$city = $record->city->name;

echo $country;
echo "</p>\n";
echo $region;
echo "</p>\n";
echo $city;
echo "</p>\n";
?>
```

Code with the function and a call to the function that does not work. The function code is identical to the previous code.

```
<?php

function find_location () {

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use GeoIp2\WebService\Client;


// This creates a Client object that can be reused across requests.
// Replace "42" with your user ID and "license_key" with your license
// key.

$client = new Client(42, 'jijlki765');

// Replace "city" with the method corresponding to the web service that
// you are using, e.g., "country", "insights".

$ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$record = $client->city($ipAddress);

$country = $record->country->name;
$region =  $record->mostSpecificSubdivision->name;
$city = $record->city->name;

echo $country;
echo "</p>\n";
echo $region;
echo "</p>\n";
echo $city;
echo "</p>\n";
}

find_location ();

?>
```

Comment: This clearly shows a lack of reading the documentation.

Comment: Dear Ismael, thank you for your encouragement.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is true. Look here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.scope Quoting: `"The use keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the global scope) or inside namespace declarations."`. A function is a new scope and isn't a namespace declaration. It took me 2 minutes. All I did was to google "php use keyword", open the documentation and read.

Comment: I understand. However I am new to PHP and I did not write the API. I am happy that other people helped me. It works now fine. If it took me 2 minutes to find the answer, I would email to you the answer and not shame you publicly for not reading the documentation. That said, I do want to thank you for replying to me the second time and explaining the mistake that I made.

Comment: Sorry if my message came out wrong. But you wouldn't have this question if you took a little more time to read the documentation. I know basically nothing about Java or C++, but I can write a decent program (without best practices) by reading the official documentation. This question clearly shows a lack of such reading. If you think I'm publicly shaming you, when you hover a comment with your mouse you can see a flag. Just click it and pick the apropriate reason.

Answer (score 1):

The error says you're using USE statement incorrectly.

Use it outside the function.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I made the change and it works great!

Answer (score 1):

Move the `use` and `require_once` outside the function block

Comment: Vishai, Thanks a lot! It works. I am relatively new to PHP.